# Cannot read from an xls file (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, spreadsheet, xls

I'm trying to read data from a xls file using

```
[a,b,c]=xlsread('list.xls', 1, 'A1:C5')
```

but as the result I get all a, b and c empty, even though there is data in the list.xls spreadsheet at the specified range. What might be the problem?

Comment: how is `list.xls` sorted? you should be more specific when addressing a question in on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html:

`[num,txt,raw] = xlsread(___)`

> additionally returns the text fields in cell array txt, and the
>   unprocessed data (numbers and text) in cell array raw using any of the
>   input arguments in the previous syntaxes. If xlRange is specified,
>   leading blank rows and columns in the worksheet that precede rows and
>   columns with data are returned in raw.

If you are only interested in data (`numbers`), you may type

```
xlsread(filename,1,'A1:C5')
```

If you have headers on the first row, call

```
[num,txt,raw] = xlsread(___)
```

`num`: array containing data;

`txt`: cell containing headers;

`raw`: cell containing headers and data.

I hope this helps